# To get column name in the result in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the below query I am getting the values in a array format and I want to get column name too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_page(IN _session integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(col1 text, col2 text) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
    select
    (SELECT array_agg(sq.*)
    FROM (SELECT user_id, user_name 
          FROM "user" 
          ) sq
    )::text,
    (SELECT array_agg(sq.*)
    FROM (SELECT client_id, client_name ,client_desc
          FROM "clients"
          ) sq
    )::text;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

The Result is :

```
"("{""(2,Test)"",""(5,Santhosh)"",""(3,Test1)""}","{""(1,Test1,Test1)"",""(2,test2,test2)"",""(3,test3,test3)""}")"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get the column name too"? Can you **edit** your question and show how you want the result?

Comment: @Patrick i want to get column name with values.So that i can able to know  particular column name value

Answer (score 0):

You could simply type them and concat into one column to use it as a row in outer select:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_page(IN _session integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(col1 text, col2 text) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
    select
    (SELECT array_agg(sq.*)
    FROM (SELECT concat('user_id: ',user_id,', user_name: ', user_name)
          FROM "user" 
          ) sq
    )::text,
    (SELECT array_agg(sq.*)
    FROM (SELECT concat('client_id: ',client_id,', client_name: ',client_name,', client_desc: ',client_desc)
          FROM "clients"
          ) sq
    )::text;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

If you want to discard information about particular column if it's value is `NULL` you can append column names conditionally (with a `CASE` statement).

Comment: It throws error No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @user2432361 There must be something wrong with your function call. It works for me.

Comment: i call this function like select load_page(1) but it throws same error

Comment: Drop all the functions with name `load_page` and recreate this one. It works fine for me, as I've said. I called it `select load_page(1)` as well and it gave output without any error. Anyways, why do you even need the input parameter here if it's not being used? Try to execute select statement outside of procedure. It should work fine - problem is not there.

Answer (score 0):

The below function does not produce the curly braces or the flood of double quotes, but it does include the column names and it is quite a bit more concise and readable and efficient than your initial version.

The `_session` parameter is never used, but I shall assume that this is all part of some larger query/function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION load_page(IN _session integer, OUT col1 text, OUT col2 text)
RETURNS SETOF record AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    SELECT string_agg('user_id: ' || user_id ||
                    ', user_name: ' || user_name, ',')
    INTO col1
    FROM "user";

    SELECT string_agg('client_id: ' || client_id ||
                    ', client_name: ' || client_name ||
                    ', client_desc: ' || client_desc, ',')
    INTO col2
    FROM "clients";

    RETURN NEXT;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```